# Multiple Lags with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I refer to the excellent post at

https://purrple.cat/blog/2018/03/02/multiple-lags-with-tidy-evaluation/

What I want to do is to create a function capable, à la dplyr, to
generate new columns which are a lagged version of existing columns in
a data frame.
For instance, you can do this manually as

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(rlang)

 d2 <- tibble(x1 =1:10, x2=10:19,  x3=50:59)

 d3 <- d2%>%mutate(x1lag1=lag(x1, 1), x1lag2=lag(x1,2))
```

but this becomes quickly tedious when you need to take several lags of
different columns.
One solution in the link above is the following

```
lags <- function(var, n=10){
 var <- enquo(var)

  indices <- seq_len(n)
  map( indices, ~quo(lag(!!var, !!.x)) ) %>%
   set_names(sprintf("lag_%s_%02d", quo_text(var), indices))

 }


d4 <- d2 %>%
  mutate( !!!lags(x1, 3), !!!lags(x2,3) )
```

Does anybody know how this could be made more general? I mean that I
would like to take a fixed number of lags of a list of columns (x1 and
x2, for instance), just by passing the list of columns and without
repeating the commands for x1 and x2.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea would be to use `...` instead of `var`, which would follow closest the spirit of your function.

To do this, it required changing `enquo()` to `enquos()`, and I use here a `crossing` and `map2`, but there's probably a more elegant way to do so...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl,
#>     flatten_int, flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along,
#>     modify, prepend, splice

d <- data_frame(x = seq_len(100),
                y = rnorm(100))
#> Warning: `data_frame()` is deprecated, use `tibble()`.
#> This warning is displayed once per session.

multijetlag <- function(data, ..., n=10){
  variable <- enquos(...)

  indices <- seq_len(n)
  combos <- crossing(indices, var =as.list(variable))

  quosures <- map2(combos$indices, combos$var,
                   ~quo(lag(!!.y, !!.x)) ) %>% 
    set_names(paste("lag", combos$indices, map_chr(combos$var, quo_text), sep = "_"))
  mutate( data, !!!quosures )

}

multijetlag(d, x, y, n=3)
#> # A tibble: 100 x 8
#>        x       y lag_1_x  lag_1_y lag_2_x  lag_2_y lag_3_x lag_3_y
#>    <int>   <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
#>  1     1  0.213       NA  NA           NA  NA           NA  NA    
#>  2     2  0.277        1   0.213       NA  NA           NA  NA    
#>  3     3 -0.517        2   0.277        1   0.213       NA  NA    
#>  4     4 -0.671        3  -0.517        2   0.277        1   0.213
#>  5     5 -1.12         4  -0.671        3  -0.517        2   0.277
#>  6     6 -0.296        5  -1.12         4  -0.671        3  -0.517
#>  7     7 -1.18         6  -0.296        5  -1.12         4  -0.671
#>  8     8  0.0582       7  -1.18         6  -0.296        5  -1.12 
#>  9     9 -0.455        8   0.0582       7  -1.18         6  -0.296
#> 10    10 -0.969        9  -0.455        8   0.0582       7  -1.18 
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>